# Can't show google map on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a google map on a bootstrap modal window, but I just manage to make the modal window appear; I can't seet the google map. I am not getting any error on the browser's console.

The button that makes the modal appear:

```
<a id="map-btn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" title="Ver en mapa"></i>
</a>
```

Tha map modal div:

```
<!-- Map Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="mapModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Zone</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

This is how I import the javascript google api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

The script to handle the google map API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:myCenter
    });

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom: 14,
          draggable: false,
          scrollwheel: false,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
        marker.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap());

    $('#mapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        console.log("a");
        //Must wait until the render of the modal appear, thats why we use the resizeMap and NOT resizingMap!! ;-)
        resizeMap();
    })

    function resizeMap() {
        if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
        console.log("b");
        setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
    }

    function resizingMap() {
        if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
        console.log("c");
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    }
</script>
```

Any idea why the map never appears?

EDIT:

If I inspect the modal element, I can see the following code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Zone</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;" id="map-canvas"><div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"><div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 164px; top: -30px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: -92px; top: -30px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; position: absolute; left: 420px; top: -30px;"></div></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: -1;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 164px; top: -30px;"><canvas width="256" height="256" style="-moz-user-select: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 256px; width: 256px;" draggable="false"></canvas></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: -92px; top: -30px;"></div><div style="width: 256px; height: 256px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 420px; top: -30px;"></div></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="overflow: hidden;"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;"><div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; visibility: inherit;"></div></div></div><div class="gm-style-pbc" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%; transition-duration: 0.3s; opacity: 0; display: none;"><p class="gm-style-pbt">Use two fingers to move the map</p></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 4; width: 100%;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div></div></div><div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><a title="Click to see this area on Google Maps" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53,-1.33&amp;z=14&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" target="_blank" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;"><div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google4.png" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></a></div><div style="background-color: white; padding: 15px 21px; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); z-index: 10000002; display: none; width: 256px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 134px; top: 5px;"><div style="padding: 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 16px;">Map Data</div><div style="font-size: 13px;"></div><div style="width: 13px; height: 13px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt6.png" style="position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div></div><div style="z-index: 1000001; position: absolute; right: 69px; bottom: 0px; width: 12px;" class="gmnoprint"><div class="gm-style-cc" style="-moz-user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px;" draggable="false"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; display: none;">Map Data</a><span style="display: none;"></span></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" class="gmnoscreen"><div style="font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); direction: ltr; text-align: right; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"></div></div><div draggable="false" style="z-index: 1000001; -moz-user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" class="gmnoprint gm-style-cc"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">Terms of Use</a></div></div><div style="width: 25px; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; display: none; margin: 10px 14px; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;"><img class="gm-fullscreen-control" draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/sv9.png" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -86px; width: 164px; height: 175px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div><div class="gm-style-cc" style="-moz-user-select: none; height: 14px; line-height: 14px; display: none; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" draggable="false"><div style="opacity: 0.7; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"><div style="width: 1px;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 1px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; padding-right: 6px; padding-left: 6px; font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/@53,-1.33,14z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?source=apiv3&amp;rapsrc=apiv3" style="font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); text-decoration: none; position: relative;" title="Report errors in the road map or imagery to Google" target="_new">Report a map error</a></div></div><div controlheight="0" controlwidth="0" draggable="false" style="margin: 10px; -moz-user-select: none; position: absolute; display: none; bottom: 14px; right: 0px;" class="gmnoprint gm-bundled-control gm-bundled-control-on-bottom"><div style="display: none; position: absolute;" class="gmnoprint"><div style="-moz-user-select: none; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" draggable="false"><div style="position: relative;" title="Zoom in"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl.png" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 120px; height: 54px;"></div></div><div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 67%; height: 1px; left: 16%; background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);"></div><div style="position: relative;" title="Zoom out"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl.png" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 120px; height: 54px;"></div></div></div></div><div controlheight="28" controlwidth="28" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; width: 28px; height: 28px; cursor: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;), default; display: none; position: absolute;" class="gm-svpc"><div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px;"></div></div><div style="display: none; position: absolute;" controlheight="0" controlwidth="28" class="gmnoprint"><div title="Rotate map 90 degrees" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl4.png" style="position: absolute; left: -141px; top: 6px; width: 170px; height: 54px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div><div class="gm-tilt" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); top: 0px; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl4.png" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 170px; height: 54px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"></div></div></div><div style="margin: 10px; z-index: 0; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; display: none; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="gmnoprint"><div class="gm-style-mtc" style="float: left;"><div title="Show street map" draggable="false" style="direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; position: relative; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; -moz-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 8px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-top-left-radius: 2px; background-clip: padding-box; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); min-width: 22px; font-weight: 500;">Map</div><div style="background-color: white; z-index: -1; padding: 2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 33px; text-align: left; display: none;"><div title="Show street map with terrain" draggable="false" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; -moz-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 6px 8px 6px 6px; direction: ltr; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); border-radius: 1px; width: 13px; height: 13px; vertical-align: middle;" role="checkbox"><div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: -2px; width: 13px; height: 11px; overflow: hidden; display: none;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -44px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 68px; height: 67px;"></div></span><label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;">Terrain</label></div></div></div><div class="gm-style-mtc" style="float: left;"><div title="Show satellite imagery" draggable="false" style="direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; position: relative; color: rgb(86, 86, 86); font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; -moz-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 8px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; background-clip: padding-box; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); border-left: 0px none; min-width: 42px;">Satellite</div><div style="background-color: white; z-index: -1; padding: 2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 33px; text-align: left; display: none;"><div title="Show imagery with street names" draggable="false" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif; -moz-user-select: none; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 6px 8px 6px 6px; direction: ltr; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; line-height: 0; font-size: 0px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); border-radius: 1px; width: 13px; height: 13px; vertical-align: middle;" role="checkbox"><div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: -2px; width: 13px; height: 11px; overflow: hidden;"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png" style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -44px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 68px; height: 67px;"></div></span><label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;">Labels</label></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
```

As you can see in the above code, the google map seems to be loading, but for some reason it is not being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I just hadn't defined a size for the #map-canvas div.

```
#map-canvas {
  width:500px;
  height:480px;
}
```